# Reset the Camera Transform with MRTK and Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I am currently developing an application for hololens 1 with Unity and MRTK and i would like to perform a very simple task.

**Reseting the camera transform to the origin.**

I try some actions but all with no sucess :

- Get the camera and play space and set their position and rotation at 0.
- Get the "MixedRealityCameraSystem" via the MRTK and use the Reset() function.

Indeed, the camera position is controlled by the user head and once the app is started i don't know how to recenter this position.

Does anyone know if there is a way to simply reset the camera transform ?

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Comment: It is not a good idea to control the position and rotation of the main camera in the runtime, it should be driven by the head, and it will exactly match the position and rotation of the head. Could you provide more information about your request? Why did you use to reset the camera transform in the runtime?

Comment: Hello Hernando, i want to reset the camera postion at each new scene loading. My architecture use a base scene with all the MRTK components(MRTK and playspace) on top of that i load additively my different scene. On some scene i record the user head postion to log them. The problem is that i want my log to start at origin, so that's why i just want to replace the camera at the origin with no rotation (just like when the game started).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, you cannot modify the camera position at runtime.

But If what you are interested in is only the position data. As a workaround, we recommend that you offset the position data of the camera before outputting it. Specifically, you first calculate the correction value between the camera and origin of the coordinate system before load your next scene. Then, after loading the new scene, subtract the correction value when outputting the head position log information.

Comment: Yes, thank you i used another game object tracker, that move exactly like the player but from the origin.